# Oracle nested SELECT loop for INSERT into new table

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find a simple(ish) way to select results from 3 tables and take the returned columns from each select and insert them all into a 4th table, which will work as a 'lookup matrix' of availability based on typeId, manufacturerId and locationId.

So for example if there are 10 TYPEID and 5 MANUFACTURERID and say 3 LOCATIONID, I would get 10x5x3 so 150 rows inserted into TABLE4

There is no direct link between tables 1,2 & 3, they are just independent tables of Product types, manufacturers and locations.
Later there will be a 'flag' column in TABLE4 to determine which availability true/false

Something like this, but I don't know the syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TYPEID FROM TABLE1
Loop
    SELECT DISTINCT MANUFACTURERID FROM TABLE2
    Loop
        SELECT DISTINCT LOCATIONID FROM TABLE3
        Loop
            INSERT INTO TABLE4 (TYPEID,MANUFACTURERID,LOCATIONID) VALUES TYPEID,MANUFACTURERID,LOCATIONID
        EndLoop
    EndLoop
EndLoop
```

I'm sure I;ve seen this done before (in a Procedure I think) but I cannot find the example, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just need `cross join`:

```
insert into table4 (TYPEID,MANUFACTURERID,LOCATIONID)
select
    t1.TYPEID,
    t2.MANUFACTURERID,
    t3.LOCATIONID
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT TYPEID FROM TABLE1
) t1 cross join (
    SELECT DISTINCT MANUFACTURERID FROM TABLE2
) t2 cross join (
    SELECT DISTINCT LOCATIONID FROM TABLE3
) t3;
```

or

```
insert into table4 (TYPEID,MANUFACTURERID,LOCATIONID)
select distinct
    t1.TYPEID,
    t2.MANUFACTURERID,
    t3.LOCATIONID
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
cross join table3 t3
```

Comment: For reference, Oracle docs on Cross Join: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html

Comment: I'd go with the first query. Why cross join all records (as in the second query), when we just want to join distinct IDs?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I agree. The second one is just clear to see but first one is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No loops needed:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE4 (TYPEID,MANUFACTURERID,LOCATIONID)
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.TYPEID, TABLE2.MANUFACTURERID, TABLE3.LOCATIONID 
FROM TABLE1 
CROSS JOIN TABLE2
CROSS JOIN TABLE3;
```